# Images not displaying my Slide Show

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I have Created the slideshow name in `page.xml` file and configure the .js and .css files.

my **.js** files are under **magento\js\scripts**, **images** are under **magento\skin\frontend\Ics\default\images\media\slideshow** and **css** are **magento\skin\frontend\Ics\default\ss**.

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="slideshow" translate="label" as="slideshow">
                <label>Slide Show</label>
            </block>

          <!-- configure the js & css files -->

               <!--Slide Show Start js files-->

                <action method="addJs">
                    <script>scripts/jquery.cycle.lite.js</script>
                </action>
                <action method="addJs">
                    <script>scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</script>
                </action>

                <!--Slide Show End-->

           <!--Slide Show Start css files-->
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>ss/dynamicslides.css</stylesheet>
            </action>

            <!--Slide Show End-->
```

I created layout.xml file in `frontend->Ics->default->layout->layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="slideshow">
            <block name="footer" type="layout/footer" template="layout/footer.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

And I have created custom layout.xml file to inclide in 2columns-rights.phtml. It is showing well by using below code.

```
<div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slideshow') ?></div>
```

Finally in my `footer.phtml` file:

```
<h1 style="background-color:rosybrown">To Day Date is :
<?php  echo $this->getDate() ?>

<h2 style="text-align: center">Slide Show</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myslides').cycle({
            fit: 1, pause: 1, timeout: 4000
        });
    });
</script>


<?php

$directory = $this->getSkinUrl('images/media/slideshow');

Zend_Debug::dump($directory);

try {
    // Styling for images
    echo '<div id="myslides">';
    foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {
        if ($item->isFile()) {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $item;
            echo '<img src="' . $path . '"/>';
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'No images found for this slideshow.<br />';
}
?>
</h1>
```

When I run this it is not displaying images but the path is returning correctly.

```
Zend_Debug::dump($directory); 

using this string(73) "http://localhost/magento/skin/frontend/Ics/default/images/media/slideshow"

No images found for this slideshow.
```

images path is correct but images are not displaying correctly.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it doesn't work, because you are nor reading a folder from the disk. You are trying to read "folder" from the web.

Comment: @Marius, using `$this->getSkinUrl()` function I got exact path. Is there another way?

Comment: `$this->getSkinUrl()` gets you the url to the folder. You need the path on the disk.

Comment: @Marius, you mean C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/skin/frontend/Ics/default/images/media/slideshow like this or ..?

Comment: I don't know, yet. If you did I would have told you. :)

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

To get the path to the skin directory instead of the url use the `getBaseUrl`.

```
$directory = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN) . 'images/media/slideshow';
```

Now you should be able to walk all the files in there. Just a minor tweak to the image outputting

```
foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {
   if ($item->isFile()) {
      $path = $this->getSkinUrl('images/media/slideshow/' . $item);
      echo '<img src="' . $path . '"/>';
   }
}
```

When outputting the image path we want the URL instead of the path so you can use `getSkinUrl` for that

Answer (score 0):

To get path to skin directory use getBaseDir() not getBaseUrl().

```
    $directory = Mage::getBaseDir(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN) . DS.'images '.DS. 'media'.DS.'slideshow';
```